# Source or Assembly for AWS SQS WCF channel transport

Tags: wcf, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

There is reference to a project that creates a channel transport for WCF based on the AWS SQS service.   All references end in dead url's.   Based on the fact that there were these references I assume it is technically feasible and viable to use SQS as a WCF transport channel with or without security.   Is this a valid assumption, and/or does anyone have source or assemblies for such a channel?   If no such source exists is it worthwhile to create such a channel for binding .NET WCF in a loose coupling pattern on AWS?

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem?

Comment: I never found the source