# Connect WCF Client/Server through AWS SQS & SNS

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, amazon-web-services

I have a WCF-Service and Client (both in C#) and want to connect them through a messaging system/queue. I've implemented a working example with the Azure Service Bus but the Azure Service Bus seems to be built mainly for connections based on WCF-Services so I don't have to implement the providing/consuming logic on my own.

With the help of a ChannelFactory and the definied Interface (+ endpoints defined in the *.conf) I'm able to call the provided functions directly in the code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITesttService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void TestConnection();

    public interface ITestServiceChannel : ITestService, IClientChannel { }
}
```

and

```
ChannelFactory<ITestServiceChannel> cf = new ChannelFactory<ITestServiceChannel>("test");
ITestServiceChannel s = cf.CreateChannel();
s.TestConnection();
```

Is it possible to realise the same functionality with the use of the AWS services? I read that it's possible to connect the AWS SNS and SQS Services to recreate the functionality but I don't have a clue how. Do I have to write the whole logic on both ends on my own after the messages are stored in the relay?

I hope I was able to explain my problem good enough :D

Greetings

Michael

Comment: Similar questions [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567762/can-wcf-bound-to-amazon-sqs) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695924/source-or-assembly-for-aws-sqs-wcf-channel-transport)